# Create route Line(driving) from origin to destination map marker after destination clicks

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I try to create a routeLine(driving) between Source marker(blue marker) and Destination after clicking on Destination marker 
[image]

this is my javascripts

```
function initMap() {
    //read the parameter values you want to send to server
    var searchItem = $("#SearchItem").val();
    var jobs = $("#Jobs").val();
    var subid = $("#bluee").val();

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'),
        {
            zoom: 8
        });

 var url = "@Url.Action("AsMapAjax", "My")";


    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
        var latlngg = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, 
          p.coords.longitude);

        var mapOptions = {
            center: latlngg,
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        //You are Here

        var iconoMarca = "../../images/bnm.png";
        mymarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: map,
            icon: iconoMarca,
            position: latlngg,
            optimized: false,
            title:"شما اینجا هستید"

        });

        var numberMarkerImg = {
            url: '../../images/webresize2.png',

            labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(30, -6)
        };


        $.post(url, { SearchItem: searchItem, jobid: jobs, subid: subid }, 
    function (res) {
            if (res.success) {
                var latLng;
                $.each(res.responseText, function (i, item) {
                    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.Lat, item.Lng);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        map: map,
                        icon: numberMarkerImg,

                        label: {
                            text: item.Title,
                            color: 'Black',
                            fontFamily: 'IranSans',
                            fontSize: '17'
                        },

                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                    });

                   var wdLink = '@Url.Action("Poster", "My")?id=' + item.Title.split(" ").join("-") + '__' + item.Id;

                    var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
'<div id="siteNotice">' +
'</div>' +
'<div  id="firstHeading">' + item.Title + '</div>' +
'<div id="bodyContent">' +
'<p><b>' + item.Preamble + '</b></p>' +
'<p><h4> <a href="'+ wdLink+'">' +
'اطلاعات بیشتر</a></h4> ' +
'</p>' +
'</div>' +
'</div>';

               var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString
                    });
                    marker.addListener('click', function () {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);

                    });

                     (marker, item);
                    ///////////////////
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $(window).resize(function () {
                            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                        });
                        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                    });


                });
                map.setCenter(latlngg);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Unfortunately I could not resolve this problem after much effort. Could you help me out.
I did it once, but with Polyline, I'm now looking for a street path from origin to destination after clicking on the destination

Comment: You need to be more specific about the issue you're encountering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yataqed/5/edit?js,output) for a simple example of how to implement the functionality you are looking for.

The following functions get the route and render it:

```
function markerClicked(destinationLocation) {
  var directionsRequest = {
    origin: sourceLocation,
    destination: destinationLocation,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  };

  directionsService.route(directionsRequest, handleDirectionResults);
}

function handleDirectionResults(result, status) {
  if (status === 'OK') {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
  } else {
    console.log(status);
  }
}
```

When a marker is clicked, the `markerClicked` function gets called and it is passed the marker's location as an argument. `markerClicked` makes a directions search request and then calls `handleDirectionResults` with the results of the request. `handleDirectionResults` renders the directions by calling the `setDirections` method on the `directionsDisplay` object (passing the results of the directions request to `setDirections`).

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help. Good luck with your app! :)